# How to Edit only node value in my RadTreeView

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, radtreeview

i have problem that after read the document i still cannot figure how to solve.
all i want to do is to add node and another one under the parent node and i want the option to add only the value of my node and not all the line, please see the attach screenshot.
[image]

At the end of [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/treeview-editing-editing-nodes.html) guide i can see `EditMode` options and i try all the 3 options.

```
RadTreeNode Node1 = radTreeView1.Nodes.Add("Node1");
RadTreeNode Node2 = radTreeView1.Nodes.Add("Node2");
Node1.Nodes.Add("Node3");
Node2.Nodes.Add("Node4");
```

in my example i want to have header to my `Node3` and `Node4` and values that i can edit for this `Nodes`

Answer (score 0):

By design you can edit only the "Text" property of a node, not the Value property. Value is usually an attribute and is hidden. The Text property is what your users see.

So, what exactly do you want to edit - text or value?

Also, what do you mean by "header" of the node?

Comment: i want to achieve the same like in my screenshot, can i have an code example ?

Comment: Check this demo on Node editing: 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/nodeediting/defaultcs.aspx